# Install a package manager inside docker container for images like 'prom/busybox'

Tags: docker, package-managers, busybox

I'm trying to troubleshoot one of my running containers, which is based on image '[prom/busybox](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/busybox/)'

I wanted to install some packages like curl, etc. This image has no default package managers like apk or apt installed. I tried looking for some way to do that, but was not successful. Any hints to do this are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other busybox images like https://github.com/progrium/busybox
There you can install those:

```
FROM progrium/busybox
RUN opkg-install curl bash git
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Thanks Hemant for the input. But, the image I'm using doesn't has 'opkg-install' package installed on it. In this case, how do I add some package manager to the image?